# How to call a bootstrap modal after 'sweetAlert' alert 'ok' clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert, sweetalert

I want to call the bootstrap modal after I click the "OK" button on a `sweetAlert` Alert.

So, after the user click the `OK` button on the `sweetAlert` alert. It will call the bootstrap modal automatically. I tried that code below in the javascript but didn't worked.

**BOOTSTRAP MODAL**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="change_password" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body change_password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script language='javascript'>
    swal({
        title: 'Sample Title',
        text: 'Hi',
        type: 'success',
        allowOutsideClick: true,
        html: true
    },
    function () {
        $('#change_password').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, its working. check your code here : [https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/baohk928/](https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/baohk928/)

Comment: make sure, you are including the `JavaScripts` in proper orders.

Comment: @tejashsoni111 my bad... thank you!! you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is working fine

```js
swal({
    title: 'Sample Title',
    text: 'Hi',
    type: 'success',
    allowOutsideClick: true,
    html: true
},
function () {
    $('#change_password').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal fade" id="change_password" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body change_password">
                Modal body
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```